# Cirq - Measure Density Matrix Function Getting First Element

Tags: programming, quantum-state, measurement, cirq

Hello I am using measure density matrix function like that:

```
for i in range (10):
    measurement_result = cirq.measure_density_matrix(state,indices=[0, 1, 2])
    print("measurement",measurement_result)
```

And my results are like that:

[image]

As you can see, I have `([0, 0, 0], array([[0.36107099-0.36107099j, 0.        +0.j        ,`  and I want to extract first part `[0, 0, 0]` (the qubit part) and then I will count how many `[0, 0, 0]` , `[0, 0, 1]` `[0, 1, 0]` … But I could not extract the first part of array. How can I get the first part `[0, 0, 0]` ?
Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a basic python usage question. You want

`first_part = measurement_result[0]` or `first_part, second_part = measurement_result`.

Comment: Can I ask one more question to you regarding the mostly python part? `cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(a)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(b)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(a)))`I have this line and I also write this line for all possible combination of a and b. I mean I have to write also `cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(a)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(a)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(a)))` and also `cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(b)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(b)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(b)))` and also `cirq.kron(cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(a)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(b)),cirq.unitary(cirq.rz(b))) `… all possible combination for a b. @Craig Gidney

Comment: Do you have an idea for that @craig-gidney